# Populate mongoose sub array of a sub array of a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a Roommate Group mongoose Schema as such,

```
var RoommateGroupSchema = new Schema({

    roommates: [ { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" } ]

});
```

I have a User mongoose Schema as such,

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

    name: String

    , billers: [{
        utilityProvider: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'UtilityProvider' }
        , fields: String
    }]

});
```

I have a Utility Provider mongoose Schema as such,

```
var UtilityProviderSchema = new Schema({

   name: String

});
```

I would like to query my Roommate Group Schema and populate ALL the sub arrays, so I'd have a result like this.

```
roommateGroup = {

    roommates: [
        {
            name: 'Sean Hill'
            , billers: [
                {
                    utilityProvider: {
                        name: 'Google Fiber'
                    }
                    , fields: 'Internet'
                },
                {
                    utilityProvider: {
                        name: 'Comcast'
                    }
                    , fields: 'Internet'
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Johnny Lingo'
            , billers: ...
        }
    ]

}
```

I've tried

```
RoommateGroupModel
    .findById(groupId)
    .populate({ path: 'roommates' })
    .exec(function(err, group){

        RoommateGroupModel.populate(group, { path: 'roommates.billers', model: 'UtilityProvider' }, function(err, populatedGroup){
            // But the billers.utilityProvider for each index in the array isn't populated, it's just the _id.
        });

    })
;
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Figured it out, just change the second populate to `roommates.billers.utilityProvider` and magic happens :)